# Stuck in transition between BlueHost and AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I cant seem to figure out how to query database information from mysql through a php file uploaded to a server back to a xamarin application after something like a http post call.

I am relatively new to database development, however I had used bluehost for php storage and querying of my app information for about a year yet cant seem to do the same with AWS. I have a relatively decent scope of what S3, EC2, and RDS do for you, however none of them seem to do what I want. In essence I want to be able to say have someone click a button on my xamarin app that creates an event for a club. Then after they click said button, it will make an http post request to an aws site that contains a php file. In that php file it will change or grab the contents of a mysql database. The only place that seems to be able to upload files is S3 but you cant seem to directly utilize php files in the JSON format that I want. Am I completely off with why you would use AWS at all, am I close but not using the right tools, or is it something else? Please give a pretty extensive description on all that I would need to do as I have been struggling to find anything at all on this topic surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6ryxPuEemo) walks through it a bit with phpstorm as your way to connect to the database and add webpages or api php files. Its pretty long but very helpful.